# Asp.net core areas localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

Hi all I'm involved in a localization project. We are working with areas and we need to create the resource file for the languages supported.
The default structure ( Resources/Controllers/controllername.culture.resx) work correctly like Microsoft docs.
we would like know the directory structure for the rest areas. We have looked for some docs but none we have found.
Thx to all

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resource files for C# objects (not views) are being resolved by the `namespace` they are in. They are relative to the `ResourcePath` set during the initialization of MVC localization.

Let's say you have set the `ResourcesPath` in your to "Resources"

`services.AddLocalization(s => s.ResourcesPath = "Resources");`

and you have a `HomeController` **without area** like this:

```
namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

then your resource files in the folder `Resources>Controllers>HomeController.{culture}.resx` will be picked up.

In case of a controller  **in a area** you might change to a different namespace like this:

```
namespace WebApp.Admin.Controllers
{
   [Area("admin")]
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

Note, this is the `HomeController` of the admin area.

In this case your resource files for this particular controller can live in the folder:

`Resources>Admin>Controllers>HomeController.{culture}.resx`

**OR** can have this naming:
`Admin.Controllers.HomeController.{culture}.resx`

This works in ASP.NET Core 1.1.0. I have updated the [AspNetCore.Identity.Localization](https://github.com/kdaveid/AspNetCore.Identity.Localization) project with an area.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Areas, just put you `controllername.culture.resx` in the `Controllers` directory (exactly where `controllername.cs` is, don't create a 'Resources' directory anywhere).

I suggest you to test with a simple resx (`controllername.resx`). If it works, you can extend it with `controllername.culture.resx`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this a bit late answer but however I want to participate, first of all setting the main path as Resource is not enough for configuration. If you have area you must follow these steps.

1. Set the main directory as Resource (or whatever yours)
2. Create the same deep folder path in Resource like Resources/Areas/Identity/Pages/here your resx file.
3. Do not forget that localizaiton works on the model hierarchy so use model namespace path when creating the folder hierarchy.